# Defer an async service call until promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to create an array of Twilio API calls to be resolved later in `Promise.all`.

`TwilioClient.messages.create(payload)` is getting called immediately inside the returned promise (A). How can I defer until the `Promise.all` chain resolves it (B)?

```
let twilioTexts = [];
if (twilioNumbers) {
    twilioTexts = twilioNumbers.map(phoneNumber => getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber));
    // (A) ==> Twilio is sending messages here upon assigning to variable `twilioTexts`.
}

await Promise.all([
  // do other stuff
  ...twilioTexts, // (B) ==> instead, Twilio should make all calls here
]);

...

function getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let payload = {
          body: `[Incoming Order!]`,
          from: 'my number',
          to: phoneNumber,
        };

        TwilioClient.messages.create(payload);
    });
}
```

---

Edit:

```
await Promise.all([
  // do other async stuff in parallel
  // check if twilioNumbers then spread map into Promise.all array
  twilioNumbers && ...twilioNumbers.map(phoneNumber => getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber)),
]);

function getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber) {
    let payload = {
        body: `[Incoming Order!]`,
        from: 'my number',
        to: phoneNumber,
    };

    return TwilioClient.messages.create(payload);
}
```

Comment: A promise does not (and should not be expected to) defer execution, it just allows for asynchronous monitoring of the request.  Think of `Promise.all` as "waiting for things that have already started executing", not as a trigger to start execution.

Comment: Also, your "getTwilioText" function is adding an extra Promise -- `TwilioClient.messages.create` already returns a Promise.  You should just be able to return that.

Comment: @Joe so it should really be the `EDIT` code above, right?

Comment: The comments in the code are not helping much to understand what you're trying to do. Can you give an example of "other stuff"? The whole point of `Promise.all` is that it waits for an array of things that are typically executing in _parallel_. If you want to do some stuff after some other stuff, put it after the other stuff, not adjacent to it.

Comment: @JLRishe the only thing `// other stuff` shows is that there's other functions being called and want the array of Twilio texts to be called in parallel with those things. My original question more clearly is "How can I create an array of async requests to be called later... in this case in the `Promise.all`"

Comment: @Growler Ok, thank you.

Comment: @JLRishe like is there some way to spread `...` operator the array of requests within  the `Promise.all`, i.e., `twilioNumbers && ...twilioNumbers.map(phoneNumber => getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber)),`

Comment: @Growler Yes, but not quite like that. I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is almost there, but `Promise.all` works on an array of promises. The `twilioNumbers &&...` line produces an array of promises, so you've got an array of promises *inside* another array, which won't work.

So you can use the spread operator:

```
await Promise.all([
  // do other stuff
  ...(twilioNumbers 
      ? twilioNumbers.map(phoneNumber => getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber))
      : []
  ),
]);

...

function getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber) {
    let payload = {
        body: `[Incoming Order!]`,
        from: 'my number',
        to: phoneNumber,
    };

    return TwilioClient.messages.create(payload);
}
```

At this point, it's a bit verbose, so you might want to factor that part out:

```
await Promise.all([
  // do other stuff
  getTwilioTexts(twilioNumbers, mailTokens),
]);

...


// returns a promise for an array
async function getTwilioTexts(numbers, mailTokens) {
    return numbers
        ? Promise.all(numbers.map(num => getTwilioText(mailTokens, num)))
        : [];
}

function getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber) {
    let payload = {
        body: `[Incoming Order!]`,
        from: 'my number',
        to: phoneNumber,
    };

    return TwilioClient.messages.create(payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
const otherPromises = // do other stuff, *triggered first*
const twilioTexts = (twilioNumbers || []).map(phoneNumber => getTwilioText(mailTokens, phoneNumber));

await Promise.all([
  ...otherPromises,
  ...twilioTexts,
]);
```

Ultimately, it shouldn't matter though as you want to run the other stuff concurrently with sending texts anyway.

Comment: Bergi thanks for the answer. The issue is `getTwilioText()` returns `TwilioClient.messages.create(payload)` which is fired right away when you create `const twilioTexts`. The array of text messages need to be fired in `Promise.all` which is why I create the array in the `Promise.all`

Comment: @Growler No, it does not need to "be fired in the `Promise.all`". It always happens before the call the `Promise.all` anyway, regardless whether you write the call to `getTwilioText` in the same line (as an argument expression) or as a separate statement in the line before. All that matters is that you put the `// do other stuff` (which you for some reason want to happen first) *before* the call to `getTwilioText`.